# Current Recycling in Electromagnets

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, plasma-physics

Has anyone figured out a way to recycle specifically the energy used to power electromagnets? Since for many applications, the Bfields required are extremely high magnitudes, the currents must match to enforce that. That is a lot of power being used and I would imagine that's probably where most of the energy expenditure is ending up? (Just an outsider guess) Has anyone figured out a way to somehow save some of the current that has run through the entire system and reuse it for the next cycle or store it for use? And I mean the energy that has run it's course through the coils and not the energy dissipated due to heat or other processes where it's lost.

I only for a moment could think of possibly utilizing capacitors in parallel, but then realized that as each builds up energy, it would create a potential at the end of the circuit that would lower the current over time (And probably very, very quickly).

Comment: Re, "save some of the current" that's like trying to save some motion. Current _is_ motion: Current is the motion of electric charge. Current (motion) is ephemeral. It isn't something you can save to use later on. But see what Andreas H. said about superconducting magnets (below). A superconducting magnet only requires power when it's "ramping up." It does not require any power to maintain a steady state magnetic field.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yeah I kind of thought that was the case, but was hoping there was potentially some nuanced or niche idea that took advantage of some property in circuits that I was unaware of to make this somehow partially work at least :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: Yes (use superconductors) and no, it is not possible (with non-superconducting wire material).

The issue is not the current but the resistance of the wire. When current flows trough the wire this dissipates power. This has nothting to do with the magnetic field per se, it is a side-effect. Moreover, for given wire material and target coil size (length/diameter) there are fundamental limits for the power needed to generate a certain magnetic field. No matter what wire diameter, wire length, how many windings one uses there is a minimum electrical power needed for certain B field.

The only way to be more efficient is to use a wire material of lower resistivity. Since copper is very good already, the only option it to use superconductors. No circuit/design trick with a copper coil of certain geometry can improve the efficiency beyond a certain limit.

Since superconductors have ideal zero resistivity this is pretty efficient. One can even turn off the supply current and short circuit the coil after initial set-up. The current will continue to circulate in the coil and create a permanent field. So besides the need for cooling, a superconducting coil is as energy efficient as a permanent magnet.

Comment: @SolomonSlow true, my wording was imprecise. Thanks. I reworded to make the difference clear.

Comment: Sorry but could you please help me understand how even if we are not using a superconductor and so the only energy lost is thermal, why we don't need to supplement the total current at all times? From my simple understanding of circuits, I=V/r and P=V*I so that would mean that equivalent power would need to be continuously supplied to maintain that current which if I is huge, then P consumption is huge too to maintain the field strengths. I am also assuming this is a DC circuit, not AC so one can't take advantage of those current properties.

Comment: You can only turn off the supply current for superconductors. For non-superconductors the current needs to be supplied at all times (as you correctly say). This is just to compensate for the resistive losses. A simple explanation: The B field is only determined by supplied current. Applied voltage is irrelevant. However due to nonzero resistance there is a nonzero voltage neede at the coil to drive the current through. This is causing the loss. For superconductor needed voltage is ideally zero, so there are no losses and we can short circuit it after set-up.

Comment: That is a very clear explanation! So would that mean that if I wanted to do a quick check on the needed power required to maintain the magnetic field magnitude, I would need to know what the resistance of the material would be and calc the V I would need to sustain that current (I=V/R), then substitute that into P=V*I to get P=V^2/R? (Assuming no thermal losses too)

Comment: @Sophia Yes, correct. I would prefer $P = I^2*R$ though. The generated B is directly proportional to I. If you do not know the resistance of the magnet you could go into more detail: You would further include two formulas 1) that relates B and I (this includes the number of windings and coil length) and b) one that relates R with resistivity, you will find out that many auxillary terms (such as number of windings and wire diameter) cancel out. You will obtain an expression that only depends on coil geometry and wire resisitivity. This is the fundamental limit I was talking about.

Comment: Great, I'll look into it and try to figure that out. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Harvard/MIT [Cambridge Electron Accelerator](https://hollisarchives.lib.harvard.edu/repositories/4/resources/4119), an electron synchrotron, operated in resonance with the 60 Hz AC mains power. It recycled the energy from the bending magnets with a gigantic inductor/capacitor "tank" circuit, similar to a radio transmitter.

Comment: Very interesting, I will take a closer look at this, thank you for the resource!